# jQuery Doesn't Work as Expected, Why?

Tags: jquery

I have a page of user comments.

```
$(p).click(function(){

    $(this).hide(200);
});
```

When user clicks on some comment this one usually disappears. Ok it works perfectly.

But when user does the same with server response, this does not work anymore

Server response is a bunch of next comments found in table (i.e custom AJAX paginator)

Server response looks like this:

```
<p id="next-id1">bla bla bla 1</p>
<p id="next-id2">bla bla bla 2</p>
```

Then this response inserts content after particular div which contains first comments in mysql table

like this:

```
$("#snow-next-btn").click(function(){

$.post('/paginator.php', {}, function(response){

    $("#comment-div").after(response);

});

});
```

Ok it works perfectly as I said. BUT this method:

```
$(p).click(function){
    $(this).hide(200);
}
```

does not work with server response anymore (but it still works with contents that has been printed by php on page load).

Where is the problem?

Comment: You are missing the closing quote [code] $(p).click(function){

    $(this).hide(200);
}); [code] let me know if that fixes your issue! cheers

Comment: This is a simple syntax error. You can find these using Internet Explorer - just press F12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.on()` with `selector` parameter (the second argument):

```
$(document).on('click', 'p', function() {
   $(this).hide(200);
})
```

I can't see your markup, so I can't tell what is the closest parent to `p`, but substitute `document` to the closest parent of `p`, so for example your markup is:

```
<div id="bla">
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
</div>
```

You'd write that as

```
$('#bla').on('click', 'p', function() {
   $(this).hide(200);
})
```

From [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector.
>
> **Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.**

Comment: +1 this should be the right answer, although it would be better to use a parent selector rather than the `document` for performance purposes

Comment: @NiftyDude how can I select all p elems with class "foo" in $('#bla').on('click', 'p<<=here with class foo', function() {
   $(this).hide(200);
})

Answer (score 1):

The event handler has not been bound to the new elements being inserted from the server's response. Instead of using `$.click()`, use `$.on()`:

```
$(document).on("click", "p", function(){
  $(this).hide( 200 );
});
```

As new elements come in, they will be bound for you. The only other solution would be to constantly be binding handlers to new elements as they drop in from the server response. Take it easy, sit back, let jQuery do the heavy lifting.

Comment: You need to use the delegated event handler syntax of `.on()` for this to work. The syntax you currently show has exactly the same effect as `.click()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Good eye. I rushed through that a bit too quickly.